# Byte array which isn't null is throwing System.NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, bluetooth

In my C# Xamarin based mobile app, I receive some data over a Bluetooth link. I then call `DecodeHeartRateCharacteristicValue (Characteristic.Value)`. You can see this routine below.

However, the first `if` line in it throws the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> at Gas_Sense.HomePage.DecodeHeartRateCharacteristicValue (System.Byte[] data) [0x00003]

I tried to put this line:

```
Debug.WriteLineIf (data[0]!=null, data [0].ToString());
```

in the routine to debug, but it throws a warning to say that `data[0]!=null` will always return `true`. However, when I try to print the value of `characteristic.value` to the screen it is blank (but it doesn't equal `null`).

So this may be an error with my print screening the wrong value type etc.

This code is based on a tested and working [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/blob/master/Sample%20Apps/BLE%20Explorer/Robotics.Mobile.BtLEExplorer.Core/Pages/CharacteristicDetail.xaml.cs) which was working before I changed the BLE service I was communicating with. So it could be a difference in the data format being received, but in that case, debugging this and working out what format it wants will likely be easier.

```
string DecodeHeartRateCharacteristicValue(byte[] data) {
    if (data == null || data.Length < 2)
        return null;

    ushort bpm = 0;
    if ((data [0] & 0x01) == 0) {
        bpm = data [1];
    } else {
        bpm = (ushort)data [1];
        bpm = (ushort)(((bpm >> 8) & 0xFF) | ((bpm << 8) & 0xFF00));
    }
}
```

I am using the [`Monkey.Robotics`](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/tree/master/Getting%20Started/Mobile_Stack) module for Xamarin. I have tried outputting two different `characteristic` properties. `Char.Value.ToString()` outputs `System.Byte[]` to the screen. `Char.StringValue` prints nothing. Not sure what this says about the type of data and possibly why it is throwing this error?

I am getting this output

> 2015-11-05 12:02:13.721 ProjectiOS[365:143055] System.Byte[]
>
> 2015-11-05 12:02:13.798 ProjectiOS[365:143055] Update Percentage
>
> 2015-11-05 12:02:13.805 ProjectiOS[365:143055] Update Replacement
>
> 2015-11-05 12:02:13.810 ProjectiOS[365:143055] System.Byte[]
>
> 2015-11-05 12:02:13.819 ProjectiOS[365:143055] Update Percentage
>
> 2015-11-05 12:02:13.826 ProjectiOS[365:143055] Update Replacement

from this code which calls the Decode function above:

```
    Debug.WriteLineIf(PercentageCharacteristic.CanUpdate, "CanUpdate");
    if (PercentageCharacteristic!=null && PercentageCharacteristic.CanUpdate) {
        PercentageCharacteristic.ValueUpdated += (s, ess) => {
            Debug.WriteLine (PercentageCharacteristic.Value.ToString());
            PercentageFill.Text = DecodeHeartRateCharacteristicValue (PercentageCharacteristic.Value);
            Debug.WriteLine("Update Percentage");
    };
    PercentageCharacteristic.StartUpdates();
    TimeCharacteristic.StartUpdates();

    }

    if (ReplacementDueCharacteristic!=null && ReplacementDueCharacteristic.CanUpdate) {
        PercentageCharacteristic.ValueUpdated += (s, ess) => {
            ReplacementDue.Text = DecodeHeartRateCharacteristicValue (ReplacementDueCharacteristic.Value);
            Debug.WriteLine("Update Replacement");
    };
    ReplacementDueCharacteristic.StartUpdates();
    }
```

So the code seems to be running through twice before it faces issues? This still happens with the feedback from the answer below. The or conditions are obviously active throughout each loop, but I could add the length check each time? Any ideas much appreciated.

A Full error trace is [here](https://gist.github.com/georgeedwards/dc42bf7935c6a0be8632) as a gist.

Comment: you should check the array for null not the first element: `if(data != null) {...}`instead of `data[0] != null`. Otherwise there will be thrown a exception when you check data[0] for null when data is null. That could be the reason why "empty" is printed

Comment: @JensHorstmann I had a check for the Char.Value which wasn't null, however, I have just checked data != null in the function, and it returns true, so still not clear why this error is being thrown? Also looked at data.length, which is 10, see my update - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With `data[0]` you are checking the first byte in the array, and since `byte` is primitive type it can't be `null`.

You have to check `data` for `null`. I also put in a check for `data.Length > 1` since you use `data[1]` (this prevents a `ArgumentException`.

```
string DecodeHeartRateCharacteristicValue(byte[] data) {
    if (data == null || data.Length < 2)
        return null;

    ushort bpm = 0;
    if ((data [0] & 0x01) == 0) {
        bpm = data [1];
    } else {
        bpm = (ushort)data [1];
        bpm = (ushort)(((bpm >> 8) & 0xFF) | ((bpm << 8) & 0xFF00));
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to check also for `data.length > 0`

Comment: Well, for `data.Length > 1` since OP accesses `data[1]`.

Comment: Or there is a bug in the framework, or you are not entirely right. If you use the above code, is the exception solved then?

Comment: `if (data == null && data.Length > 1)` makes no sense. It will try to retrieve `data.Length` *only* when `data == null`. The check should be `if (data == null || data.Length < 2)` if you want to avoid invalid accesses of `data[0]` and `data[1]`

Comment: @PatrickHofman OK, I have updated the question, performing that check, the data is definitely not null, although, it works for the first two loops. Any ideas?

Comment: @CSharper I have updated the question with new debug info

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Can you provide the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: @CSharper Sure, here is a gist of the full error output, https://gist.github.com/georgeedwards/dc42bf7935c6a0be8632

Comment: What is `AddToAzure`? And what is on this line? `/Users/georgeedwards/Documents/Gas-Sense Personal Mobile App/Gas_Sense/HomePage.xaml.cs:210`?